# What does the error mean: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace

Tags: c#, string, path, whitespace

My project will parse XML file and do some job.

If i'm inside VS 2005 and I run my project, it works fine.

If i try to execute my project (console application / .exe) i got this error:

**Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace**

Comment: debug arguments in project?

Comment: Show your code and probably someone will show you your error

Comment: Best to read it for what it says: you are trying to open a file whose name is an empty string.

Comment: Sounds like your application expects a filename to be passed to it, and that is being provided by the IDE in Project --> Properties --> Debug Tab --> Command line arguments.  This is why it works when run from the IDE.  You need to provide a filename to work with when you run it directly, as well as fix the code so that it doesn't crash when no filename was provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue while using visual studio 2017 **Error: 'path' cannot be an empty string ("")**

Below solution worked for me.

**Solution Steps :**

1. Right click on solution.
2. Click Disable Lightweight Solution Load
3. Then restart your Visual studio.
4. Then try to Build/Rebuild solution.

I hope, now you are able to build.

**Reason to face this issue in VS2017 :**

As I researched, Microsoft provided lots of new features in visual studio 2017. One is :

**Visual Studio starts faster, is more responsive, and uses less memory than before.**

To achieve this feature we need to Enable Lightweight Solution load.

For more information [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio)